# Laravel access foreign key table column in blade

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

How can I access a table column using a foreign key in blade so far I have this but it does not work.

Inquiry Model / relations

```
public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
}
public function device()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Device::class);
}
```

Client Model

```
public function inquiry()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Inquiry::class);
}
public function devices()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Device::class);
}
```

Device Model

```
public function inquiry()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Inquiry::class);
}
```

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $inquiries = Inquiry::all();
    return view('stream.index', compact('inquiries'));
}
```

View

```
@foreach($inquiries as $inquiryKey => $inquiryValue)
    <tr>
        // stream id is the foreign that table has a column with names ...
        <th scope="row">{{ $inquiryValue->stream_id }}</th>        // works
        <th scope="row">{{ $inquiryValue->stream_id->name }}</th>  // does not work -> trying to get property of none object
```

Comment: stream_id is which table field ?

Comment: you just pass in foreach like $inquiries->client then you can use  client table data

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd could you give me an example code please

Comment: sure i give you example in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access attribute `name` of `stream_id`, it's just an integer, what you may try is `$inquiryValue->client->name` or i think, `$inquiryValue->client->first()->name`

Be sure to let Laravel know that `stream_id` is the key used for your relations.

Comment: I thinks this worked `$inquiryValue->client->name` I will check it further and may accept your answer later

Comment: each object in Inquiry::all is an Inquiry model, thus letting you use relationships `client` and `device` thus, doing `$inquiryValue->client` will return the client related to it, you can now access its name. You should also let Laravel know that you're using stream_id as your foreign_key in your relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with this example like :

**Updated answer**

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $inquiries = Inquiry::all();
    return view('stream.index', compact('inquiries'));
}
```

View file

```
@foreach($inquiries as $inquiryKey => $inquiryValue)
    <tr>
        // stream id is the foreign that table has a column with names ...
        <th scope="row">{{ $inquiryValue->client->name }}</th>        // works
    </tr
@endforeach
```

Comment: Did not work, thus I do not understand `Inquiry::with('client')->get();` returns the same as `Inquiry::all();`, the error: `property [client] does not exists on this collection instance`

Comment: table names are clients, inquries, devices

Comment: The Collection looks like this if I dd(Inquiry::with('client')->get());  https://kopy.io/wVj1y

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd that wont work because Inquiry's relationship is `client` not `clients`

Comment: Property client does not exists in collection instance

Answer (score 0):

if you name it *stream_id* than i think it's better u have a table name *streams*, if u want to get the client data from inquiry, than u should have *client_id* column in your *inquiry* table, same for the device, add *device_id* column to your *inquiry* table

How to access it:
`@foreach($inquiries as $inquiryKey => $inquiryValue)
{{$inquiryValue->client->name}}
{{$inquiryValue->device->name}}
@endforeach`